# What is the purpose of the "Death Clock" during boss fights?

Tags: diablo-iii

When everyone dies in a party during a boss fight, a red timer starting at 1 minute appears near their corpse and counts down. What is the purpose of this timer?

[image]

I imagine that is how long a party has to do something before the boss resets, but what can be done? There is no way to revive during a boss fight without another player's help.

Comment: I do not have any experience, but, besides the dots and followers, maybe if another player joins the party, and the timer is still running he can teleport trough banner to your location and the figth follows normally. But It's just a wild guess

Comment: @NunoFreitas If your party members are in a boss fight you can not teleport to them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Damage over time spells could still be on the boss, if it is a close fight it might be enough to take him out. I have not had it happen vs a boss but i have seen champion packs die due to my WD dots after I died my self.

Comment: You forgot the (possibly still) living DoT: your follower.

Comment: Me and my friend had this happen to us the first time we killed the butcher his Hydra finished him off as we died.